# Need clarification on Static/Dynamic Types and Vtables

Tags: java, vtable

So I got my homework back saying I only got 15/30 points correct, but there was no explanation on which question(s) I got wrong or why it was wrong. I have an exam coming up and I'd like to figure this out before I have to take it. Thusly I was hoping someone could help me understand what I got right/wrong? and why?

So here was my assignment:

Consider the following Java program:

```
   public class Base {

    public        void m(Object o) { System.out.println("Base.m(Object)"); }
    public static void m(String s) { System.out.println("Base.m(String)"); }
    public        void m(Class c)  { System.out.println("Base.m(Class)");  }
   }

   public class Derived extends Base {

    public        void m(Object o) { System.out.println("Derived.m(Object)"); }
    public static void m(String s) { System.out.println("Derived.m(String)"); }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      Base b = new Derived();
      b.m(new Object());
      b.m(new Integer(5));
      b.m("Hello");
      b.m(b.getClass());
    } 
   }
```

- Question 1 (5 Points): What is the Static Type of b in Derived.main()?

  My Answer: Base
- Question 2 (5 Points): What is the Dynamic type of b in Derived.main()?

  My Answer: Derived
- Question 3 (20 Points): What are the correctly ordered entries in Derived’s vtable for our 
                      translator? Please use classname.methodname(typenames)” notation. 
                      Also, ignore the first entry, which is __isa.

  My Answer: Derived’s vtable-

  - Derived.m(Object)
  - Base.m(Class)

  I'm under the impression that Base.m(String s) and Derived.m(String s) are both static methods; thus they would not be included in the vtable. Also, I assumed that Derived.m(Object) would be used instead of Base.m(Object) and thus would not be included in Derived's Vtable.

Comment: What sort of test expects you to know the inane specifics of how the compiler implements polymorphism?

Comment: A crazy German Professor's Final Exam on Object Oriented Programming. He said all the questions on the final will have a Star Trek Theme to it. I'm looking at last year's harry Potter Themed final Exam and I want to shoot myself. I mean, I like Harry Potter and all, but c'mon son, Star Trek??

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1 (5 Points): What is the Static Type of b in Derived.main()?

Correct: Static type is always the declared type, in this case Base: `Base b = new Derived();`

> Question 2 (5 Points): What is the Dynamic type of b in Derived.main()?

Correct: Dynamic type is the type that the variable is pointing to, in this case Derived

> Question 3 (20 Points): What are the correctly ordered entries in Derived’s vtable for our translator? Please use classname.methodname(typenames)” notation. Also, ignore the first entry, which is __isa.

- Derived.m(Object) ***overrides*** Base.m(Object): ***Derived.m(Object)*** is correct
- Base.m(Class c) ***overloads*** Derived.m(Object): ***Base.m(Class c)*** is correct

If static methods were to be taken into account:

- Derived.m(String s) would ***shadow*** Base.m(String s). When methods are shadowed, the method depends purely on the ***static type***; in this case the static type is Base and therefore `Base.m(String s)` would be called;

Here's a bizarre example for instance:

```
Derived a = null;
a.m("World");
```

This prints `Derived.m(String)`, why? The dynamic type of `a` is null, but `Derived.m(String)` only cares about the static type of `a` which is Derived